# OpenVPN detection

Tags: detection, openvpn

Is it possible to detect whether or not a visiting computer is using OpenVPN to tunnel from a remote location?  I know that through packet inspection I can determine an OpenVPN connection between the end-user computer and the OpenVPN server regardless of port, but what about detection of the end-user computer using OpenVPN, after the traffic has been NAT'd and it hits my remote server?  Are their any giveaways in the packets (even the smallest crumb)?

Comment: The same question was asked just an hour after I asked @ http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71774/how-can-i-detect-a-vpn-connection-even-just-in-some-cases-to-get-the-real-loca

Comment: @greasemonkey - That question was asked a week ago.  Why are you asking?  One major factor in using VPNs is to disguise the origin location, both from the ultimate destination and anybody else snooping on the line - if you could detect the true location it would defeat the purpose.  Further, just knowing that something is running a VPN service isn't necessarily enough to tell you that a given connection is using the service, vs coming from the computer running the VPN itself.